# Call C++ function from (C) header file gives linker error

Tags: c++, c

I am integrating a library (lwip) and I want to reroute the logging mechanism from `printf` to something I wrote myself (which logs directly to my uart).

In some header file the following code exists

```
/** Platform specific diagnostic output.\n
 * Note the default implementation pulls in printf, which may
 * in turn pull in a lot of standard libary code. In resource-constrained 
 * systems, this should be defined to something less resource-consuming.
 */
#ifndef LWIP_PLATFORM_DIAG
#define LWIP_PLATFORM_DIAG(x) do {printf x;} while(0)
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#endif
```

I replaced this line

```
#define LWIP_PLATFORM_DIAG(x) do {printf x;} while(0)
```

with

```
#define LWIP_PLATFORM_DIAG(x) do {logLineToUart x;} while(0)
```

I am using the same signature for my function as the `printf` signature:

```
void logLineToUart(const char * log, ...);
```

And I placed that function in my own header `lwiplogging.h`, which I include in the header which defines `LWIP_PLATFORM_DIAG`

And, I implement the function in a C++ file:

```
void logLineToUart(const char * log, ...)
{
    uart3.Write(log);
    uart3.Write("\r\n");
}
```

NOTE: uart3 is an object of my `Uart` class. Hence it's C++ code. I suspect this is the problem, but I can't figure out how to correct my error. Adding `extern "C"` to the function doesn't seem to solve it either.

The linker error I get:

```
Linking .pio\build\nucleo_f446ze\firmware.elf
.pio/build/nucleo_f446ze/lib997/lwip/api/api_lib.o: In function `netconn_send':
api_lib.c:(.text.netconn_send+0x26): undefined reference to `logLineToUart'
.pio/build/nucleo_f446ze/lib997/lwip/api/sockets.o: In function `tryget_socket_unconn_nouse':
sockets.c:(.text.tryget_socket_unconn_nouse+0xa): undefined reference to `logLineToUart'
.pio/build/nucleo_f446ze/lib997/lwip/api/sockets.o: In function `get_socket':
sockets.c:(.text.get_socket+0x14): undefined reference to `logLineToUart'
.pio/build/nucleo_f446ze/lib997/lwip/api/sockets.o: In function `lwip_connect':
sockets.c:(.text.lwip_connect+0x22): undefined reference to `logLineToUart'
sockets.c:(.text.lwip_connect+0x38): undefined reference to `logLineToUart'
.pio/build/nucleo_f446ze/lib997/lwip/api/sockets.o:sockets.c:(.text.lwip_connect+0x7e): more undefined references to `logLineToUart' follow
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
*** [.pio\build\nucleo_f446ze\firmware.elf] Error 1
```

What am I doing wrong?

UPDATE

The error I get when I declare the function as extern "C"

[image]

UPDATE 2:

This does compile:

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
void logLineToUart(const char * log, ...);

#endif

void logLineToUart(const char * log, ...);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: Where is your `extern "C"` ?  You say it didn't work for you, but you must have put it in the wrong place; it is the solution.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`extern "C" void logLineToUart(const char * log, ...);`

You need to tell it to make the name C-linker compatible the first time it is seen.

## update

The `extern "C"` is only when compiling as C++.  It is not legal syntax in C.  You can use `extern` by itself (it is implied if you leave it off).

### Editorial

That's not very friendly... C++ accommodates sharing header files with C by accepting syntax that would not apply to C++, just to make it easy to use the same header file contents.  In particular, using `(void)` for empty parameter lists (which is "an abomination") and allowing a comma in variadic function parameter lists ( `(int x ...)` is how C++ originally defined it; when the same feature got incorporated into ANSI C they used `(int x, ...)` with a superfluous comma that is not needed by the grammar.)  C++ compilers accept both of these to make it easier to consume C headers...

But, you have to add `extern "C"` around everything.  This introduces conditional compilation anyway, even though C++ accepts the C syntax.  Note that for a single declaration, `extern int foo (int);` the `extern` is allowed and implied if you leave it out.  If the C compiler allowed the linkage specification even though only "C" is available, it would make life easier.  Note that in most cases, the C and C++ implementation are the same compiler suite, and often one language supports some features of the other as extensions.  It would be cool if `gcc` etc. supported `extern "C++"` in C mode, since that code base certainly does know how the name encodes the parameters.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I tried, but that won't compile. lib\lwip\src\include/lwip/arch.h:83:8: error: expected identifier or '(' before string constant. It gives that error on the  extern "C" declaration. I'll update my question with a screenshot

Comment: Updated question once more, I don't know if this is the appropriate solution, but I added the "fix". If you could comment on that (and whether or not it can be done better) I might learn something out of this. Thx